# Change Image Source to Amazon using Jquery

Tags: jquery

On my site at http://www.chiwah.us/product_p/chiwahguitar.htm I am using the following code to replace the src of every image so that the image loads from Amazon instead of www.chiwah.us.

When i check the results on this page http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/CuCilXywL/www.chiwah.us/product_p/chiwahguitar.htm it says the images are loading from both the main site as well as from Amazon, I want to load the images only from Amazon. Is there any problem with my following script?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  try{

    var len=$("img").each(function(){

        if($(this).attr("src").indexOf("/v/")!=-1 )
        {
        url=$(this).attr("src").replace("/v/","https://s3.amazonaws.com/Chiwah/"); 

        $(this).attr("src",url);

        //alert($(this).attr("src"));
        }

        if( $(this).attr("src").indexOf("http://www.chiwah.us/v/")!=-1)
        {
            url=$(this).attr("src").replace("http://www.chiwah.us/v/","https://s3.amazonaws.com/Chiwah/"); 

            $(this).attr("src",url);
        }

        if( $(this).attr("src").indexOf("v/")!=-1)
        {
            url=$(this).attr("src").replace("v/","https://s3.amazonaws.com/Chiwah/"); 

            $(this).attr("src",url);
        }
    }).length;


    var butt=$("input").each(function(){

      if($(this).attr("type")=="image")
      {
       if($(this).attr("src").indexOf("/v/")!=-1)
        {

        url=$(this).attr("src").replace("/v/","https://s3.amazonaws.com/Chiwah/");
        $(this).attr("src",url);
        //alert($(this).attr("src"));
        }

        if($(this).attr("src").indexOf("http://www.chiwah.us/v/")!=-1)
        {

        url=$(this).attr("src").replace("http://www.chiwah.us/v/","https://s3.amazonaws.com/Chiwah/");

        $(this).attr("src",url);
        //alert($(this).attr("src"));
        }
        if($(this).attr("src").indexOf("v/")!=-1)
        {

        url=$(this).attr("src").replace("v/","https://s3.amazonaws.com/Chiwah/");
        $(this).attr("src",url);
        //alert($(this).attr("src"));
        }
      }
    }).length;

    }catch(e)
    {
//  alert(e.message);
    }


});

</script>
```

Comment: Can you add some HTML code that you were testing against.

Comment: The browser will have started loading (at least some of) the original images before your code runs - are you sure that's not what you're seeing?